# How to concatenate text with variable value on VueJS component property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using *Vue Material* components I want concatenate a text with a variable's value to make the `md-content` text.

```
<md-dialog-confirm
  :md-active.sync="showDialogConfirmDelete"
  md-title="Deletar Fornecedor"
  md-content="Concate this with {{fornecedorToDelete.nome}}"
></md-dialog-confirm>

...

data() {
   return { fornecedorToDelete: {nome: "Name"} }
}
```

but it doesn't works, the `md-content`'s value is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a computed property:

```
:md-content="mdContent"
```

Then define `mdContent` in your computed property:

```
computed: {
  mdContent: {
    get: function() {
      return `Concate this with ${this.fornecedorToDelete.nome}`
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can (ew) do it the dirty way:

```
:md-content="`Concate this with ${fornecedorToDelete.nome}`"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind `md-content` to a concatenated string with the data property as follows:

```
 :md-content="Concate this with+'fornecedorToDelete.nome'"
```